# Java 32bits y JDK ¿son lo mismo?

Tags: java

Me descargué Java 32 bits y la descripción dice que es Java Platform SE binary; tiene un tamaño de 66,3 MB. A la vez tengo el JDK instalado. Estoy aprendiendo a realizar aplicaciones para ver en un navegador. ¿El Java Platform ya contiene el jdk o debo tener los dos instalados? ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre ellos? Muchas gracias. Saludos

Comment: Lo que se encuentra en las descargas de Java SE es el JDK. [aquí](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). Eso fue lo que descargaste? Y por favor, ejecuta `java -version` en tu terminal para saber qué tienes instalado

Comment: Quedo muy agradecida por la pronta respuesta. Es verdad, en la consola se puede ver; el problema es que no sabía si estaba apilando un material sobre otro que ya tenía o necesitaba ambos. .Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Java Platform SE binary o  JRE (java runtime enviroment) es un paquete que contiene las herramientas necesarias para correr programas en java ya compilados (la maquina virtual , librerias, etc) con este no podes crear programas nuevos. esto se usa normalmente si queres correr algun software ya compilado hecho en java en tu computadora

JDK es java development kit tiene todo lo que tiene la JRE pero ademas tiene el compilador y otras herramientas para que puedas crear y compilar programas

Si lo que queres es programar tenes que instalar la JDK.

a su vez tenes varias versiones de java

- JAVA SE: Standard Edition, para aplicaciones de escritorio
- JAVA EE: Enterprise Edition,tiene funcionalidades adicionales que
  extienden JAVA SE, principalmente para hacer aplicaciones web
- JAVA ME: Mobile Edition, un conjunto de funcionalidades para
  dispositivos mobiles

Answer (score 2):

**Con JDK es suficiente**

El JDK es el Kit de desarrollo de Java donde viene todo el empaquetado de librerias y herramientas para la creacion de programas en JAVA ,
Por lo que tengo entendido JavaPlatform es una coleccion de programas donde incluye:

- librerias para desarrollo
- un compilador
- etc..

Personalmente solo uso el OpenJDK en su version 11 (que es lo mismo a JDK , solo que gratuito , sin licencias para el uso de Java11LTS)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la pronta respuesta. La verdad, fue esclarecedora desde el título. Saludos